# Post on a users wall on behalf of my app (not the user)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-wall

For several years i have managed to sort things out without posting my own question, but by readings others instead. However, after reading over 200 useless posts, i've decided it's time i get some help.

I'm building a facebook app, and what i wan't to do is extremelly simple to explain. I wan't to notify a certain user about some event in real-time. For example, **"the tv show you want to watch starts in an hour"**. Unfortunately, facebook doesn't allow apps to send private messages to users (which was my first choice). The standard way of publishing on a users wall on HIS BEHALF is not good either, because no notification is triggered. Therefore, my idea is to post on his wall on behalf of the app (or any similar action that will trigger a notification).

I know about app requests, but they are not what i'm looking for either, as you can see, they do not match what i want to do.

Also please note that the event may be particular for each user, so making a post or something for EVERYBODY to see is not an option (**"Peter, you have dinner with stacy in an hour"**).

Firstly, i want to know if posting on the apps behalf (or facebook page, or any other idea) is possible.

If it isn't, i would like to see any other ideas to sort this out. Remember, it's extremelly important to trigger the notification.

Thanks for your time reading this, but i have one last request.

Although what i want to do is pretty simple, there are plenty of similar issues being disscused, which may lead to confusion, so please be SURE that you fully understood what i am asking before answering.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What about opening an event and auto inviting the specific user to the event?
Events invites trigger a notification and the only thing you need is the user's email address which you can easily get.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What you proposed is quite clever, but i'm pretty sure a user can't auto invite himself to an event he created (i've just tried). If you have any other suggestions, please let me know

Comment: @FelipeCoirolo I can't really find a definitive answer and most of my trial & error sessions returned no results. Can an App create an event on behalf of itself?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if an app posting on your wall initiates a notification*.  Although posting to a users wall on behalf of an app is certainly possible.
You can follow the instructions on [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), under the "App Login" title, and with that retrieve the correct access token you need to make calls as your app.
In order to have the functionality you specified, you'll have to request the `offline_access` permission from your users - this will allow you to post to your users wall even when he/she is not currently in or using your app. (or even logged into facebook)

---

*
Usually these posts on behalf of an app are user initiated - ie the user pressed "post to my wall."